# how to insert xml nodet at a defined points

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

xslt have function(like substring vice versa) or how to solve it? I had xml:

```
<document>
<Line>
    <Line-Item>
        <LineNumber>10</LineNumber>
        <EAN>111</EAN>
        <BIC>123123</BIC>
        <SIC>AVD091</SIC>
    </Line-Item>
</Line>
<Line>
    <Line-Item>
        <LineNumber>20</LineNumber>
        <EAN>22222</EAN>
        <BIC>3232332</BIC>
        <SIC>AVD25482</SIC>
    </Line-Item>
</Line>
</document>
```

needed output:

```
10        111     123123      AVD091
20        22222   3232332     AVD25482
```

Field line number start from 1 column position, EAN start from 11 column position, BIC start from 19 and SIC from 31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this XSLT 1.0 style-sheet. The pad template is an XSLT 1.0 version of Martin's mf:pad function.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document/Line/Line-Item"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="pad">
  <xsl:param name="value" />
  <xsl:param name="width" />
  <xsl:variable name="col-max" select="'                    '"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring( concat($value,$col-max), 1, $width)" /> 
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="Line-Item" >

 <xsl:call-template name="pad" >
  <xsl:with-param name="value" select="LineNumber"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="width" select="10" />
 </xsl:call-template>  

 <xsl:call-template name="pad" >
  <xsl:with-param name="value" select="EAN"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="width" select="8" />
 </xsl:call-template>  

 <xsl:call-template name="pad" >
  <xsl:with-param name="value" select="BIC"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="width" select="12" />
 </xsl:call-template>  

 <xsl:value-of select="SIC" /> 

 <xsl:value-of select="'&#x0A;'" />
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="*" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer I will use it.

Answer (score 2):

**This short and generic transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:fields>
  <fieldset name="LineNumber" width="10"/>
  <fieldset name="EAN" width="8"/>
  <fieldset name="BIC" width="12"/>
 </my:fields>

 <xsl:variable name="vSpaces" select="'                    '"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vFields" select="document('')/*/my:fields/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="Line-Item">
     <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Line-Item/*">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat(.,
           substring($vSpaces,
                     1,
                      $vFields[@name = name(current())]/@width
                     -
                      string-length()
                      )
           )"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<document>
    <Line>
        <Line-Item>
            <LineNumber>10</LineNumber>
            <EAN>111</EAN>
            <BIC>123123</BIC>
            <SIC>AVD091</SIC>
        </Line-Item>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Line-Item>
            <LineNumber>20</LineNumber>
            <EAN>22222</EAN>
            <BIC>3232332</BIC>
            <SIC>AVD25482</SIC>
        </Line-Item>
    </Line>
</document>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
10        111     123123      AVD091
20        22222   3232332     AVD25482
```

**Do note**:

The element `my:fields` can be put in its own XML document. Thus, no modifications would be required to the XSLT code if some fields widths need to be modified.

Comment: @Petras: You are welcome. Please, consider accepting the shorter and more generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample stylesheet (XSLT 2.0, sorry, started writing before your comment indicated a request for 1.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf">

<xsl:param name="col-max" as="xs:string" select="'                    '"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:pad" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:param name="col-length" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="concat($input, substring($col-max, 1, $col-length - string-length($input)))"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="Line">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LineNumber">
  <xsl:sequence select="mf:pad(., 10)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EAN">
  <xsl:sequence select="mf:pad(., 9)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="BIC">
  <xsl:sequence select="mf:pad(., 12)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SIC">
  <xsl:sequence select="mf:pad(., string-length())"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```